# Debug flag with 'make'

Tags: makefile, cmake

I use CMake to generate all the necessary files for the make command to be issued later. In CMake, I can set the build type (and other relevant variables) to debug or -g and then use gdb to debug the executable once it is generated by make. My question is: Can I pass an argument to the make command to tell it compile in debug or release mode instead of having to set it in CMake? If I want to frequently switch between release and debug during compile, I need to keep going back to CMake. If I can avoid that, it would be great.
I hope the question is clear.

Thanks

Comment: you could create separate targets for your Debug and Release versions, with different `-g` flags?

Comment: You mean two different build locations one for each? I guess that can work. Thats how visual studio organizes as well right (to make sure I am seeing eye to eye with your comment).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use an out-of-source-system in which you would use 2 different build directories with different cmake-flags. Imagine your directory-structure is as follows:

```
source/CMakeLists.txt
build-release/
build/debug/
```

When you create your environment you would do like this:

in `build-release`

```
cmake ../source -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

in `build-debug`

```
cmake ../source -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

Then to switch between the two build-types you only need to change directories and run make.